# Applied potential to Saturated silver electrode

Tags: electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

I recently did my first cyclic voltammetry. I used a saturated silver reference electrode and two platinum working and counter electrode. This was done with an IKA electrasyn 2.0 device, my parameters I can choose are my maximum applied voltage and sweep rate. When I get my data back I can only find the current vs the applied voltage (so not vs the Ag/AgCl reference electrode even though I used it in the experiment). How do i convert this data, maybe I was going to add ferrocene so I have a reference but maybe that won't be necessary.[image: Picture of my CV experiment]

Comment: I am afraid you cannot. Are you sure you have configured the experiment properly ? As both potentials of Pt electrodes toward Ag/AgCl electrode are "floating".

Comment: Maybe have a quick look here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128616/79678. Your reference electrode is already taken into account on the abscissa of the plot. That said, it is always good to test known electroactive standards, e.g., ferrocene.